# Connecting to local server MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, wamp

I am currently trying to connect a Joomla installation on my local machine to a MYSQL database on another computer on my network (which is running WAMP too).

I can access the WAMP installation on the other computer using the URL 'bwm-ws' through my browser, so have been trying to connect to the MYSQL on this by changing the MYSQL host in the Joomla config to the following. (I have tried three different URL's in the config as follows:

```
public $host = 'localhost';
```

I also tried the IP of the local server:

```
public $host = 'http://192.168.1.108';
```

and the IP with the specific MYSQL port:

```
public $host = 'http://192.168.1.108:3306'
```

This didn't work and causes the website to time out and say give the following database error:

```
Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error
```

As you can see non of these settings seem to work and cause a database error. I have also changed the httpd.conf settings to

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

This doesn't seem to help either.

Does anybody else know or have any idea how I would go about getting a connection to another server (on the same networks) to allow a remote MYSQL connection to it? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This may, or may not, help, but can you connect to the MySQL server with a 3rd party tool (ie: Navicat) & if not, does it give you the same error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection to the database is controlled by these 3 variables in `configuration.php` as you have worked out for yourself.

```
public $host = 'localhost';
public $user = 'userid';
public $password = 'password';
```

So you would do this :-

```
public $host = '192.168.1.108';
public $user = 'userid';
public $password = 'password';
```

So forget the `http://` you are not connecting to a webserver, you are using `TCP/IP` to connect to a database server.

But you must also check that the userid is setup on the `192.168.1.108` MySQL server machine, with the correct password and is allowed to login from the client PC i.e.  `userid@client-ip`, also it has to have the correct privileges on the joomla database you have presumably setup on the MySQL server on the 192.168.1.108 machine.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. When you mean 'setup' on the server do you mean within PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is just an interface for MySQL. You're going to want to [set up the user within MySQL (through PHPMyAdmin, using SQL tab)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql)

Comment: Probably, yes. By that I mean using phpMyAdmin or any other tool like it or even the `mysql console` if you know how to use it and how to write the relevant commands. But basically whatever you use to setup Accounts on your MySQL server. Its probably easier using phpMyAdmin. [This may help](http://www.infosolutionsgoa.com/tutor/phpmyadmin-database-management.html)

Comment: Worked a dream. Added the user with specific IP into MYSQL users and now allows connection. Thanks everyone!